# How to refresh both data and categoryAxis in Kendo Chart?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, charts, kendo-ui

I have a problem in *AngularJS + TS* when it comes to **refreshing the data and axis in Kendo chart**.

There are 3 problems:

- `.refresh()` and `.redraw()` didn't exist,
- Data not refreshing,
- Category Axis (**X axis**) not refreshing.

How to be able to use `.refresh()` etc. and then be able to change both data & X axis, when a new data is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

*I was dealing with it for few days (as a Junior BACKEND dev...), so I want to share my solution with you :)*

- TypeScript

First, you need to do "helper" field called "chart", with Partial to properly deal with optional (`'myField?'`).
Probably you've got just `.ChartOptions`,

```
chartOptions: kendo.dataviz.ui.ChartOptions;
```

but only `.Chart` has `.refresh()` method, so create new field called chart:

```
chart: Partial<kendo.dataviz.ui.Chart>;
```

and in the initialization method of your chart, do an observable from dataSource in your `chartOptions`:

```
    this.chartOptions = {
// Other fields of the chartOptions
                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: (options) => {

// Your logic to create new data array

                                options.success(yourNewData);
                            }
                        }})
                };
            }
```

and then create new method (refresh), that should look like this:

```
    this.chartOptions.dataSource.read();
    'labels' in this.chart.options.categoryAxis ? this.chart.options.categoryAxis.labels.step = step : null;
    this.chart.refresh();
```

- HTML:

**(remember to set options from chartOptions, not .chart.options, because you cannot get options from non-existing object.)**

```
<div>
    <div kendo-chart="$ctrl.chart" k-options="$ctrl.chartOptions"></div>
</div>
```

**Also remember, when you close your chart (eg. by `ng-if`), then you need to run `init` function again, because `refresh` function would throw an error about "undefined".**